# Angular js $http example Web API

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

Here is my API controller method

```
 [HttpPut]

        public List<Employee> PutEmployee(int EmpID, Employee empl)
        {
            empl.EmpID = EmpID;
            int index = emp.GetEmployees().FindIndex(i => i.EmpID == empl.EmpID);
            emp.GetEmployees().RemoveAt(index);
            emp.GetEmployees().Add(empl);
            return emp.GetEmployees();
        }
```

Here is angularJS controller

```
   $scope.UpdateEmp = function () {
        var empl = $scope.Employee;
        empHttpFactory.update(empl.EmpID,empl ).success(function () { // update method in my resource uses $resource
            $location.path('/EmpList'); //redirect to list
        });

    };
```

Here is my service code

```
 var resource={
        update: function (ID, empl) {

           // var empl = {'EmpID':1,'FirstName':'Kailash', 'Salary':62000};
            var params = { EmpID: ID, empval: empl };

                         // return $http.put('../api/Emp/Put', { EmpID: ID , empval:   return $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '../api/Emp/Put',
                data: params

            })
```

empl });

```
        }
    }

    return resource;
```

When i do the debug, i could see the value for EMPID and empval in the angularjs controller and service but when it comes to API controller part, i m getting the value for EMPID alone but not for empval, its coming as null. can someone provide me working sample of it. i m new to AngularJS

Update 1 :

I have replaced the Params to data in my http call. My API method expecting the parameter in the body as per my controller method. I changed the http call accordingly and it started working fine. Also in my first argument to the controller method, I m using the variable name as EmpID, if I have used as "id", then probably, id would have been passed as the parameter in the URL itself

```
 return $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: '../api/Emp/Put',
                    data: params

                })
```

Updated Question:
This is regarding the $resource

In $resource documentation, 2nd argument is parameter and the 3rd has list of actions where I can mention the parameters. But if you see from my example, I haven't explicitly used params option but passing data to my controller method. Its working as expected because its taking it as data. Why it so???

$resource('../../Employee/PutEmployee/', {  }, { update: { method: 'PUT', empval: { "EmpID": 1, "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Peter", "Salary": 60000 } ,isArray: true } })

Comment: What is the REST api supposed to receive. If you had to document this REST service, what would you say about its URL, the body of the request, etc.?

Comment: @JB Nizet, I updated my question with the solution I used and also I have another question which I posted

Comment: @JBNizet, I updated my question with the solution I used and also I have another question which I posted

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of my toying web api project.

```
public class MoviesApiController: ApiController {
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Movie> Get() { /* your implementation here */ }
[HttpGet]
public Movie Get(int Id) { /* your implementation here */ }
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMEssage Put(int Id) {/* your impl */ }
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Movie movie) {/* impl */}
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id) { /*impl */ }
```

In fiddler, calll get  with endpoint like:  api/MoviesApi/

Call with specific movie id with endpoint like: api/MoviesApi/1

To issue a put, in fiddler change action to put, and rest endpoint like: api/MoviesApi/1

The same url goes for post and delete. Make sure you change it appropriately in fiddler

As for angularjs, I use $resource instead of $http, but your url should be the same. An example of my angularjs service:

```
angular.module("your_name").factory("your_name", ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('/api/MoviesApi/:Id', null, {
'update' : {method: 'PUT'}});
```

Comment: But for update(Put), you need to pass the model as well rit? Atleast in my case, i m passing the model as well for update. So in this case, how i can decorate my API and how i call it in angular.

Comment: You can do like @JB Nizet's answer for using $http, I am just showing how you use the url because in your question, your backend put method's name is PutEmployee but in your angularjs, the url is api/Employee/Put and I think that's why you get the error "the request resource does not support http method put"

Comment: But it says the message as but it says the message as “{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}

Comment: In fiddler, did you change your verb to put?

Comment: In don't have fiddler with me now, but if I remeber correctly, in fiddler in composer tab, on the left of the url input, there is a drop down list that let you change from get, post, delete,..bla bla. Also, as JB Nizet's comment, looks like you have problem with interpret webapi

Comment: I updated my question with soln and posted another query as well

Comment: The first {} is params for request (aka binding for the request), the second {} is the payload (aka action)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the REST service is bound to the URL `api/Emp/:EmpID`, with method PUT, and expects to receive the new employee data as JSON, in the request body.

But that's not what you're doing in your angular code. You're sending a PUT request on the URL `../api/Emp/Put?EmpID=<theID>&empval=<the employee>`, without any request body.

What you need to do is

```
$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: '../api/Emp/' + ID,
    data: empl
});
```

or, simpler:

```
$http.put('../api/Emp/' + ID, empl);
```

Comment: I decorated my Put method like this [HttpPut]
        [Route("~/api/Emp/ID")] and i changed my service code as    return $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '../api/Emp/' + ID,
                data: empVal

            }) but in fiddler it shows the message as {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}

Comment: OK. It seems that your problem is more about how to implement your backend and interpret the annotations (which I assume are C# annotations), rather than an AngularJS problem. Please tag your question with the appropriate tags (.Net, C#, I guess).

Comment: Are you doing RESTful, if so, I think you may need to change your api action from PutEmployee to Put then you use url like : '..api/Emp/:Id'. Or you can keep it the way it is which in your case use custom action name, and in your javascript, change url to something like ../api/PutEmployee/:ID

Comment: @JackyNguyen can you please share me simple working sample with API controller method and how it needs to be called in $http as well

Comment: @JBNizet, hi, i have posted another query related to angularjs, could you help me with it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654437/angularjs-resource-cache